# Why is $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \bigg( \bigg| \frac{n^{n^2} (n+2)^{(n+1)^2}}{(n+1)^{2n^2+2n+1}} \bigg| \bigg)=e$?

Tags: limits, exponential-function

I know that the following is the correct limit, but I have difficulties in seeing just why this is.
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left| \frac{n^{n^2} (n+2)^{(n+1)^2}}{(n+1)^{2n^2+2n+1}}\right|=e$$

Comment: It's $$\biggl(\frac{n}{n+1}\biggr)^{n^2}\cdot \biggl(\frac{n+2}{n+1}\biggr)^{(n+1)^2}.$$ Do you know how to handle that?

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**. By using the Taylor series expansion, as $x \to 0$, one has
$$
\log(1+x)=x-\frac{x}2+\frac{x^3}3+o(x^3)
$$ giving, as $n \to \infty$, 
$$
\begin{align}
-n^2\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)&=-n+\frac12-\frac1{3n}+o\left(\frac1{n}\right)
\\\\
(n+1)^2\log\left(1+\frac1{n+1}\right)&=n+\frac12+\frac1{3n}+o\left(\frac1{n}\right)
\end{align}
$$ then one may write, as $n \to \infty$, 
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{n^{n^2} (n+2)^{(n+1)^2}}{(n+1)^{2n^2+2n+1}}&=\frac{n^{n^2} (n+2)^{(n+1)^2}}{(n+1)^{n^2}(n+1)^{(n+1)^2}}
\\\\&=\left(1+\frac1n \right)^{-n^2}\left(1+\frac1{n+1} \right)^{(n+1)^2}
\\\\&=e^{-n^2\log(1+1/n)}\cdot e^{(n+1)^2\log(1+1/(n+1))}
\\\\&=e^{1/2+1/2+o(1/n)}
\\\\&=e^{1+o(1/n)}
\end{align}
$$ which yields the announced result.

Answer (score 3):

Starting with $2 n^2 + 2n + 1 = n^2 + (n+1)^2$ then
\begin{align}
\frac{n^{n^2} (n+2)^{(n+1)^2}}{(n+1)^{2n^2+2n+1}} &= \left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{n^{2}} \, \left( \frac{n+2}{n+1} \right)^{(n+1)^{2}} \\
&= \frac{ \left(1 + \frac{1}{n+1} \right)^{(n+1)^{2}} }{ \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^{n^{2}}} \\
&= \frac{e^{(n+1)^{2} \, \ln(a_{n+1})} }{ e^{n^{2} \, \ln(a_{n})} } \hspace{5mm}  a_{n} = 1 + \frac{1}{n}  \\
&= e^{n^{2} \, \ln\left(1 + \frac{2}{n}\right) + n \, \ln\left( 1 + \frac{1}{n+1} \right) } \, e^{\ln\left( \left(1 + \frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1} \right)}
\end{align}
Now
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left[\frac{n^{n^2} (n+2)^{(n+1)^2}}{(n+1)^{2n^2+2n+1}} \right] &= e^{0 + 0} \, e^{\ln(e)} = e.
\end{align}

Comment: +1 ... and nice to see that you've returned.  How are you?

Comment: @Dr.MV I have been active in the review section but not in the problem section until recently, again. You have been providing some nice solutions. Outside of this, not too bad, have been trying to work on a paper and papers take up a lot of time. I pose the same question to you.

Comment: Yes, I published in refereed journals and the process can be lengthy.  I am the managing partner at a consultancy and doing the same types of things (e.g., marketing the firm, engaging clients).  The work is not always as fun as solving math problems, but it can pose challenging problems.  What is the topic of your paper?

Comment: @Dr.MV I sent a message to the corresponding email presented in a profile.